# How to get the response string and parse it using ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I am using `ASIHTTPRequest` to connect to a web service. I am not getting what I should do next. When i run the code provided below I am not getting any output or response string. Program is running without any errors. What should I do to get the response string and parse it?

**Code**

```
-(void)callWebService
{

    //this is a typical url for REST webservice, where you can specify the method that you want to call and the parameters directly with GET

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDzl0Ozijg2C47iYfKgBWWkAbZE_wCJ-2U&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures"];
    //https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDzl0Ozijg2C47iYfKgBWWkAbZE_wCJ-2U&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures&callback=handleResponse    

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestCompleted:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestError:)];

    [request setDelegate:self];
      // [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestCompleted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
}

- (void)requestError:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with `responseString`? How do you know it's empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working just fine. Just add some NSLogs in your delegate methods.  `NSLog(@"ResponseString:%@",responseString);` and log the error to  `NSLog(@"Error:%@",[error description]);`.

May be your problem is from the default time out of 10 sec for ASIHttpRequest.

Edit:

```
- (void)requestCompleted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"ResponseString:%@",responseString);
}

- (void)requestError:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error:%@",[error description]);
}
```

Edit 2:

```
 if([responseString length]){
        // do some thing
    }
```

To convert from NSString to NSDictionary just use [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).

```
NSDictionary *returnDict = [responseString JSONValue];
```

Comment: thank u ..where i shd add?and where i shd check for response string?i am not able to fix  this issue from 3 days...i am not getting wat i shd do next to parse it..plz help me

Comment: yup everthing run fines hwo to check the response string and parse it?